# fixing color bar in a seaborn heatmap

Tags: seaborn, colorbar, logarithm

Good morning everyone,

I'd like tu represent a heatmap with its color bar in log scale. For that pourpose, I used LogNorm function but the scale bar only shows 2 values(picture attached 1). How could I modify this bar, maybe its limits, to make it appear as a "normal" color bar (pic attached 2).

here the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm


df = pd.read_excel(r'X.xlsx', 
                   )


df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.full((14, 23), np.nan))


n=7 
m = 0 

for i in df0:
    while n < 10: 
        df0.loc[10, n] = df['mechanic threshold N'][m] 
        n = n + 1
        m = m + 1 
        
df0.loc[11, 8] = df['mechanic threshold N'][3]



n= 7+5
m = 0 

for i in df0:
    while n < 10+5:
        df0.loc[10, n] = df['mechanic threshold Y'][m] 
        n = n + 1 
        m = m + 1 
        
df0.loc[11, 8+5] = df['mechanic threshold Y'][3]




sns.heatmap(df0,
            cmap="mako", norm=LogNorm()).set(title='X', xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], 
            ) 
                                                          
                                                               
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0) 



plt.show()
```

here the pics:

1.[heatmap with the bad color bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaaJY.png)
2. [heatmap with a color bar as I would like it to appear. I know that the logarithmic scale is different, but leave it more like this and not just that 2 values appear as in the previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv2kH.png)

here part of the data frame:

| point | mechanic threshold N | mechanic threshold Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.047857143 | 0.064 |
| 2 | 0.051 | 0.058 |
| 3 | 0.046470588 | 0.037058824 |
| 4 | 0.097142857 | 0.082 |

Thank you all very much in advance, greetings!

I tried vmin and vmax method but it didn't work